# In MongoDB find out when last query to a collection was? (Removing stale collections)

Tags: mongodb

I would like to find out how old/stale a collection is, I was wondering if there was a way to know when the last query was made to a collection, or even get a list of all collections last access date.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mongodb collection document _id is of the following format `"_id" : ObjectId("57bee0cbc9735bf0b80c23e0")` then Mongodb stores the create document timestamp.

This can be retrieved by executing the following query

```
db.newcollection.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("57bee0cbc9735bf0b80c23e0")})._id.getTimestamp();
```

the result would be an ISODate like this `ISODate("2016-08-25T12:12:59Z")`

> find out how old/stale a collection

There is no predefined libraries available in mongodb to track the oldness of a collection. But it is doable by maintaining a log where we can keep an entry when we are accessing a collection.

References

[ObjectID.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectIDs-DocumentTimestamps)

[Log messages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/)

[Rotate Log files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/)

[db.collection.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.stats/)

Comment: But I guess I have no way of knowing which the oldest record is without evaluating each one?

Also this would only give the age of when that doc was created, not updated.

Comment: Yes updation timestamp of a document is not stored by mongodb, but it can be done by maintaining a log for all collection crud operations.